# qqline() equivalent for a normal probability plot of edf

Tags: r, plot, ecdf

I made a plot of an empirical distribution function (EDF) using plot.ecdf(x, ...). 
In order to visualize normality, I'm looking in r for a qqline equivalent to draw a simple diagonal line in my plot.
The normplot() function in MATLAB is doing the same thing (See the red line in the plot on this link: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/normplot.html). Thanks.

Comment: Please supply a reproducible example, or just have a look at `?abline`.

Comment: `?qqnorm` and `?qqline` ?

Comment: Do you want to compare your distribution with a normal dist, or with an idealized (i.e. model) version of your distribution? If the former, `qqnorm` ; if the latter `qqplot` .

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, just call `qqline()`:

```
x <- ecdf(rnorm(10))
plot.ecdf(x)
qqline(x)
```

[image]